Let $a,b\in \mathbb N$. If $a+b=101$ and $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ has its maximum value then calculate $a\cdot b$
The problem
Let $a,b\in \mathbb N$. If $a+b=101$ and $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ has its maximum value then calculate $a\cdot b$
My idea
$(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2=a+b+ 2\cdot \sqrt{ab}= 101 + 2\cdot \sqrt{ab}$
For $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ to has its maximum we need $2\cdot \sqrt{ab}$ to has its maximum value.
By AM-GM: $2\cdot \sqrt{ab} \leq 101$ and the equality happens if $a=b=\frac{101}{2}$, the thing is that $a$ and $b$ have to be natural numbers.
I don't know what else to do. I hope one of you can help me! thanks!

This is a one variable problem...just set $b=101-a$.   For that matter, it's a finite problem, and can be solved with a simple search.  But solving the continuous problem speeds up the discrete search.

@lulu What do you mean by ,,a simple search"...Do I have to take every number till 50 and check it? Is there any way of making the circle of numbers smaller?

Searching $50$ values is nearly instantaneous.  But it's not necessary.  The plot of $F(x)=\sqrt x+\sqrt {101-x}$ increases to a unique max at $50.5$ and then decreases.  Thus the optimal solution is the unordered pair ${50,51}$.

WLOG, $b\ge a$, as $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$, we can't have the equality because if not, $b = a = 50.5$. Then, $b>a$.
From the condition $a+b = 101$, we have:
$$b \ge 51 >50 \ge a \tag{1}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
(1) \implies (b-51)(a-50) \le 0 &\iff ab \le 50 \underbrace{(a+b)}_{=101} +\underbrace{a}_{\le 50} -50\cdot 51\\
&\implies \color{red}{ab \le 50\cdot 101 + 50 - 50\cdot 51 = 2550 }
\end{align}$$
The equality occurs if and only if $(a,b) = (50,51)$. Of course, if we take back the assumption $b \ge a$, we have two solution  $(a,b) = (50,51)$ or  $(a,b) = (51,50)$.
Finally, we have
$$\color{red}{a \cdot b = 2550}$$

This doesn't seem to take into account the fact that $a,b$ must maximize $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ subject to the constraints.  It seems to just be maximizing $ab$ directly.

@DanielSchepler I did this because the OP already proved in the question: "maximize $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$" is equivalent to "maximize $a\cdot b$".

Take $f(x) = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{101 - x}$. It is well defined on $[0,101]$.
Consider $g(x) = \sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt x$. It is well known that $g$ is decreasing function since the growth of $\sqrt x$ slows down. Then consider the function $h(x) = \sqrt{101 - x} - \sqrt {100-x}$ which must be increasing since it's just $g(-x)$ shifted by some value. Thus, $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ intersect exactly once which is when $$\begin{align}\sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt x &= \sqrt{101 - x} - \sqrt{100-x}
\\ \sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt{100-x} &= \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{101-x} && \text{Rearrange} \\ 2\sqrt{(x+1)(100-x)} &= 2\sqrt{x(101-x)} && \text{Square}\\ (x+1)(100-x) &= x(101-x) && \text{Square} \\ -x^2 + 99x + 100 &= 101x -x^2 \\ x=50
\end{align}$$
This means $g(x) > h(x)$ for $x\in [0,50)$ and $g(x)<h(x)$ for $x\in (50,100]$. This however proves a more important proposition: rearranging gives $g(x) - h(x) > 0 \iff \sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{101 - x} + \sqrt{100-x} \iff f(x+1) - f(x) >0$ for $x\in [0,50)$ and similarly $f(x+1)-f(x)<0$ for $x\in (50,100]$. Thus the graph of $f$ over $[0,101] \cap \mathbb Z$ increases till $50$ and then decreases from $51$ onwards. Thus it suffices to check $x=50$ and $x=51$, both of which yield the maximum. Then $a=50\land b=101-a=51$ or $a=51\land b = 101-a=50$. So in either case $$ab = 50\cdot 51 = 2550$$

This is exactly the idea i presented in the post. The thing is a and b must be natural numbers

@IONELABUCIU I apologize. I've edited the post accordingly.
